# Number of sequences of given type

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, number-theory

Consider that there is sequence $a$ of length $n$ ,$a=[a_i,0\le i\le n]$. Now you are given with $\text{lcm}$ of some pairs of number from list that is, $\operatorname{lcm}(a_i,a_j)=k$ for $0\le i,j\le n$ and $i\neq j$ and $k$ is specific for given pair. Find number of sequences of $a$ that satisfy given $\text{lcm}$'s.

I thought that if $\text{lcm}$ pairs are less than number of distinct number of pairs from sequence,than answer if infinity and if there is any contradicting pair then answer is $0$ and for remaining case that is where $\text{lcm}$ involving every element is present then i do not know how to solve. Could anyone help me with this question.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $i! = j$ to $i \neq j$ which is vastly different but I think what you meant :)

Comment: This sounds like quite a tricky problem. To simplify I would suggest viewing integers instead as vectors of their prime exponents. E.g. $14 = 2^1 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^0 \cdot 7^1 \equiv [1,0,0,1]$. Then $\text{lcm}(a, b)$ is simply the elementwise $\max(a', b')$ where $a', b'$ are the vector representations of $a, b$.

Comment: @user808094 Please refrain from crossposting, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754543/number-of-sequences-of-given-type.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is at least #P-hard. I'll describe the algorithm which reduces the problem to the simplest case where its hardness can be seen.

Note that if there are numbers that don't participate in any constraints, then the answer is either $0$ or $\infty$. We solve the problem for the rest of the numbers and return $0$ if there are $0$ combinations for them, and $\infty$ otherwise.

The idea is the following.

- Like @orip suggested, represent each number as a product of primes, e.g. $40 = 2^3 * 5^1$.
- For all primes $p_1, \ldots, p_k$, which we encounter in any numbers, we solve the problem separately. In the end, the final answer is $ans(p_1) \times \cdots \times ans(p_k)$.

So, we have to solve a problem for each prime number $p_i$. We replace each number with its power of $p_i$. E.g. when we process prime $2$ and encounter number $40$, we replace $40$ with $3$, since $40$ contains $2$ in the third power. As @orip mentioned, each
$lcm$ constraint becomes a $max$ constraint: $lcm(a_i,a_j) = 40 \to \max(a_i, a_j) = 3$.

The algorithm is the following:

1. First pass: we find a bound on all $a_i$'s. For each $a_i$, find all constraints it participates in, and take the minimum of them. E.g. if $\max(a_i, a_1) = 2$, $\max(a_i, a_3)=5$ and $\max(a_i,a_9) = 10$, then we know that $a_i \le \min(2, 5, 10) = 2$.
2. Now we can find that some constraints can't be satisfied (because $\max(a_i, a_j)=b_{ij}$, but we have bounds $a_i < b_{ij}$ and $a_j < b_{ij}$). In this case, we just report $0$. Otherwise, the problem has some solutions.
3. We can determine some values of $a_i$'s. For example, if we know that $a_1 \le 2$, $a_2 \le 3$ and $\max(a_1, a_2) = 3$, then we know that $a_2=3$.
4. Now for some constraints $\max(a_i, a_j)=b_{ij}$ we still don't know the answer. Note that it means that $a_i$ and $a_j$ have the same bound (namely, $b_{ij}$) (otherwise we would have fixed one of them in the previous step).

   Therefore, we can build the following graph: for each unknown $a_i$ we create a vertex $v_i$, and for each constraint $\max(a_i,a_j)=b_{ij}$ we create an edge $(v_i, v_j)$. Note that for any connected component in this graph, all its vertices correspond to the same bound. We solve the problem for each connected component separately and, again, multiply the answers.

   Now, we want each edge in this graph to have at least one endpoint with value $b$ (our bound). In other words, we want to find a *vertex cover*, and assign $b$ to all vertices from the vertex cover. We can assign any number $0,\ldots,b-1$ ($b$ options) to all other vertices. Therefore, the total number of acceptable assignments is the following:

   $$\sum_{k=1}^n |\text{vertex covers of size $k$}| \cdot b^{n-k}$$

   where $n$ is the number of vertices in the connected component. In the simplest case, when $b=1$, the problem becomes to find the number of vertex covers of a given graph. This problem is known to be #P-hard, and you don't have a hope to solve it efficiently.

   For some specific cases, there may be a simple solution. For example, when we have constraints for all pairs (and therefore the graph is a clique), the expression is just $(b+1)^n - b^n$ (all possible assignments except assignments when no vertex has value $b$).